# Incorrect format of generator expression? python

Tags: python, printing, generator, generator-expression

I'm trying to change several `if` and `else` statements into generator expressions and for some reason it gives me an error.

So my `if` and `else` statement is this..

```
sequence = 'CTGAGTAGC'
reference = 'ATGACTGCC'

for seq, ref in zip(sequence,reference):
    if seq == ref:
        print seq,'-',ref
    else:
        print seq,' ',ref
```

I've tried above if and else statement into this generator expression..

```
tmp = (seq,'-',ref if seq==ref else seq,' ',ref for seq,ref in zip(sequence,reference))
print tmp
```

and it gives me an error like this:

```
tmp = (seq,'-',ref if seq==ref else seq,' ',ref for seq,ref in zip(sequence,reference))
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Do you want  tuples of (seq, delimiter,ref) or a strings of seq+delimiter+ref?

Comment: @ NightShade, I want strings of seq+delimiter+ref

Comment: hm I don't understand why I got down voted for... my question format was wrong or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disambiguate the tuples in the expression:

```
tmp = ((seq, '-', ref) if seq == ref else (seq, ' ', ref)
       for seq, ref in zip(sequence, reference))
```

or even

```
tmp = ((seq, '-' if seq == ref else ' ', ref)
       for seq, ref in zip(sequence, reference))
```

Demo:

```
>>> sequence = 'CTGAGTAGC'
>>> reference = 'ATGACTGCC'
>>> tmp = ((seq, '-' if seq == ref else ' ', ref)
...        for seq, ref in zip(sequence, reference))
>>> for tup in tmp:
...     print tup
... 
('C', ' ', 'A')
('T', '-', 'T')
('G', '-', 'G')
('A', '-', 'A')
('G', ' ', 'C')
('T', '-', 'T')
('A', ' ', 'G')
('G', ' ', 'C')
('C', '-', 'C')
```

Comment: Hmm, I think it should be `((seq, '-', ref) if seq == ref else (seq, ' ', ref) for...)`, no?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: there you go, illustrating why it the disambiguation is needed here. :-)

Comment: @Pieters The above if and else statement actually prints out the strings but the solutions that you posted gives me <generator object <genexpr> at 0x10d5c5dc0> this..

Comment: @Danny: you asked for a generator expression, that's what a generator expression looks like when printed. You need to *iterate* over the generator to access the results it yields.

Comment: @ Pieters Oh so i guess I have to use another for loop.... Isn't that gonna make the whole code O(n^2) complexity ? Sorry, I'm new to the python

Comment: @Pieters Oh, I see, So I guess the code will run faster if I just stick with if and else statements right?

Comment: @Danny: no, it won't. A generator expression produces results *on demand*. As you loop, the generator loop is executed. That makes it O(N) complexity. Use a generator expression to optimise *memory use*; the generator expression uses O(1) constant memory as only one result is 'live' at a time.

Comment: Also, two for loops is still O(n), because O(2n) is still O(n). Two nested for loops heads towards O(n^2) territory

Comment: @  Pieters Thanks for perfect explanation, i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
print seq,'-',ref
```

In this type of statement, `print` is putting the strings together for you. `seq, '-', ref` anywhere else would be a tuple, and if you don't want a tuple....

```
tmp = ( "-".join(i) if i[0] == i[1] else " ".join(i) for i in zip(sequence,reference))

for i in tmp:
    print i
```

`"-".join(i) if i[0] == i[1] else " ".join(i)` is a python ternary expression (which takes the form `A if condition else B`)